# UIWebView reloads video when closing its parent view

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uiwebview

I am trying to play a video from my UIWebView and play its audio in the background. This works fine, however when I lock my screen / close out of the view their is a slight delay in sound. The audio goes dead for a split second every time. Why is this happening? Is there a way to access avaudiosession of a UIWebview so I can get more information? Thank you.

Ive tried

- adding all info.plist recommendations
- enabling background mode
- arbitrary loads = true
- avaudiosession.shared().setactive = true
- laying out views if needed

  ```
  webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false 
  webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true

      webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com"))
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIWebview is deprecated in swift 4 so for that you need to use WKWebview in same way. read user guide to use class of WKWebview.

Comment: This fixed it. Didn't realize the library i was using was so old!